# Media Partition formating error

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a ONDA Vi30D, ICS 4.03.  While wiping the media partition, i get this error, "mkfs.vfat failed on /dev/block/avnftl* (1)".  Any help please.

Comment: Are you wiping the media partition via Recovery?  Also, why are you trying this in the first place? Is there a larger problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Yes via recovery. I am doing it because while factory data reset it automatically formats the /media.  In doing so it generates the error and stops. However the ICS is running fine. Except that it has errors accessing the media on its internal SD Card. It hangs. And after a restart it takes more than 10 mins to scan sdcard.